# How to run javascript timeouts after each other instead of in parallel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the timeOut function in jquery two times inside one function such as:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        Do something
    },10000); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        Do something
    },10000); 
});
```

Here is a sample of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln74dLp2/3/

How can I chain the two timeouts after each other, instead of them running in parallel?

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour, what you have shown works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln74dLp2/. Can you please set up a jsfiddle which has the issue you describe. Note I reduced the timeout simply to be able to test it quicker.

Comment: Do you mean that the second function is executing as soon as you click, or it's not waiting after the first function?

Comment: It is not waiting after the first function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you have something misconfigured. Your code works just fine (though I dropped the timeout down to 1 second for the demo):

```js
$('#one').hide();
$('#two').hide();
$('.button').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#one').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#two').show();
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p id="one">
    Here is the first sentence
  </p>
  <p id="two">
    Here is the second sentence
  </p>
</div>
<button class="button">
  click
</button>
```

A second option, which is probably overkill, but if you end up with a lot of these elements, you could use a single function that iterates over all the elements delaying each one by a multiple of 5 seconds:

```js
$('#one').hide();
$('#two').hide();
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('#one, #two').each(function(index) {
     $(this).delay(5000 * (index + 1)).queue(function() { $(this).show(); });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p id="one">
    Here is the first sentence
  </p>
  <p id="two">
    Here is the second sentence
  </p>
</div>
<button class="button">
  click
</button>
```

Comment: This should really be a comment.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, probably, though with a working example maybe OP can see what they may have done wrong. My guess is this question will get closed anyway.

Comment: In the above, when you click the button, the browser waits 5 seconds then executes the rest immediately without waiting another 5 seconds for the second sentence to show.

Comment: @JakeA: Ok, you didn't explain that you wanted two separate events 5 seconds apart. To do that, either set the timeouts for 5 and 10 seconds, or chain the timeouts. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want for the first function to execute before second gets executed, do this

```
$('.button').click(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            Do something
            setTimeout(function(){
               Do something 
            },10000); 
        },10000); 

    });
```